# Center items vertically without setting height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically center certain items within a table cell.  I've tried most solutions on stackoverflow and several other sites without any luck.

In this cell, the image is stuck at the top of the table cell, while the text is properly centered vertically:

```
<tr>
    <td class='sidebar-middle'>   <!--sets a left and right border-->
        <a target="_blank" href="data/Standards.pdf">
            <div style='width: 100%;text-align: center;overflow: hidden;'>
                <div style='float: left;width: 34%; text-align: center;height: 100%;'>
                    <img src='images/logo.jpg' alt='Standards' style='width: 80px;vertical-align: middle;'/>
                </div>
                <p style='float: right; vertical-align: middle;width: 64%;'>Local Facility Standards to be Followed</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

However, using the same method, this DOES seem to work:

```
<tr>
    <td class='sidebar-bottom'> <!--sets a left, right, and bottom border-->
        <a target="_blank" href="Policies.html">
            <div style='width: 100%;text-align: center;overflow: hidden;'>
                <div style='float: left;width: 35%; text-align: center;height: 100%;'>
                    <img src='images/patch.png' alt='Policies' style='height: 80px;vertical-align: middle;'/>
                </div>
                <p style='float: right; vertical-align: middle;width: 64%;'>Policies</p>
            </div>
        </a>
   </td>
```

In the first (frustrating) example, the image is 112 pixels in height, scaled down to 30.  In the second (working) example, the image is 122 pixels in height, scaled down to 80.  I suspect that image height has something to do with it, but can't get any further in resolving the problem.

Comment: Vertical align will have no effect on floated elements...I'd start there.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an actual table or are you using a table for layout? This table structure doesn't really make sense, why can't it be two table cells? If it's not an actual table I would very strongly suggest not using tables and using Flexbox for alignment if support allows.

Comment: I'm using a table for layout.  +1 'cuz I didn't know about flexbox.

Comment: @Paulie_D:  it seems to work for the <p> tag, which is "float: right".  Just not for the image in the div.

Comment: @hidanielle:  I was going to try Flexbox on another part of the site, but the standard for our organization is IE9 and Flexbox requires IE11.  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While assigning classes to the elements I didn't see a change. When I replaced the `<tr>` and `<td>` with `<div>` and `<section>` it didn't change. It just works like the way you wanted it to. There's no style info provided for classes, `.sidebar-middle` and `.sidebar-bottom` so that might be your problem (or the rest of the code you neglected to post). **Note:** I didn't need to modify the `div.C` or the `<section>`s I added, so table components may have not been needed and the floats were sufficient.

When using inline styling heavily, your HTML gets cluttered and there's no easy way of fixing it should you have many lines of that coding disaster. As Paulie_D and hidanielle already stated, your `vertical-align` does not function on floated elements, and HTML table -layouts are so 90s. In the 21st century we use [`table-*` CSS properties](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero).

#### SNIPPET

```css
.A {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.B {
  float: left;
  width: 34%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.note {
  float: right;
  width: 64%;
}
```

```html
<div class='C'>
  <section class='sidebar-middle'>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf">
      <div class='A'>
        <div class='B'>
          <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png' alt='Lenna' class='img' />
        </div>
        <p class='note'>Local Facility Standards to be Followed</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </section>
</div>



<div class='C'>
  <section class='sidebar-bottom'>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com">
      <div class='A'>
        <div class='B'>
          <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png' alt='Lenna' class='img'>
        </div>
        <p class='note'>Policies</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've been yelled at on here for posting "extraneous code", but everything falls into a normal html table.  The sidebar styles simply add borders (middle -- border-left, border-right; bottom -- border-left, border-right, border-bottom) as the comment in the html code mentions and are no factor.  As for, vertical-align not working on floated elements...it may say it doesn't, but I'm looking at a result that does.  Perhaps it doesn't work on floated divs, but it seems to be working fine on floated <p>.

Comment: As for the "..in the 21st century" snark, I'm a java developer that got assigned maintaining this web page as an additional duty.  As such, the level of my html skills is kind of irrelevant to me especially when resources like stackoverflow are available.

Comment: I was being facetious, I use tables for layout on occasion and the world hasn't ended yet. It looks as if you are getting the correct layout already. The reason why your `<p>` are in the middle is because it's under a div that's 100% height. If you notice in my Snippet, I have removed the `vertical-align` and the `<p>` are still in the middle. If it's an extra duty, then the skill you apply to said duty is very relevant. Being a Java programmer, it'll take you a day or so before master HTML no sweat. But seriously, you will get nothing but attitude if you show crap and ppl know u can do better

Comment: This is the closest to the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floats, use CSS Tables (since you started with an actual table for layout).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.inner {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 34%;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}
img {
  width: 80px;
}
.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 64%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="data/Standards.pdf">
  <div class="inner">

    <div class="left">

      <img src='http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80' alt='Standards' />
    </div>

    <p class="right">Local Facility Standards to be Followed</p>

  </div>
</a>
```